# C# value is declared but never used

Tags: c#

I have a try and catch where I am catching different error types:

```
catch (XmlException XmlExp)
{
    return false; 
}

catch (XmlSchemaException XmlSchExp)
{
    return false; 
}
catch (Exception GenExp)
{
    throw GenExp;
}
```

Notice that XMLException XMLExp is declared but never used. Is it possible to catch the XMLException without declaring a local variable?

Is this valid code:

```
catch (XmlException)
{
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Have you ever try to remove `XmlSchExp` text (nothing else)? Try. :)

Comment: seriously, just try! it takes less time than posting the question. also, just use `throw;` instead of `throw GenExp;` is your intent is to rethrow the exception

Comment: Also it is bad idea to throw exception inside catch block: `throw GenExp;`. You'll loose stack trace. Simply write 'throw;' to rethrow a caught exception.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, like this

```
catch (XmlException)
{
    return false; 
}

catch (XmlSchemaException)
{
    return false; 
}

catch (Exception GenExp)
{
     // inspect or use GenExp
     throw;
}
```

Comment: Use catch(Exception) { throw } instead. This keeps the stracktrace information correct. Rethrowing the exception destroys the original stacktrace

Comment: @Sander - or just omit that catch block altogether if it's just rethrowing

Comment: @Phil Nash - That's even better ofcourse, if all the catch block's doing is rethrowing

Answer (score 6):

Do this

```
catch (XmlException)
{
   return false; 
}

catch (XmlSchemaException)
{
   return false; 
}

catch (Exception)
{
   throw;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use

```
catch (XmlException)
{
    throw;
}
```

When you throw a specific exception object like `throw ex` the stack trace gets overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just miss out the variable name:

```
catch (XmlException)
{
    return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

```
catch (XmlException)
{
  return false; 
}
```

Of course, all other rules regarding exceptions apply - i.e. not using them for flow control, avoiding any situations where they might be thrown, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (XmlException)
{
    return false; 
}
catch (XmlSchemaException)
{
    return false; 
}
catch (Exception GenExp)
{
    throw GenExp;
}
```

Just omit the variable name.
For the last catch I'd advise using `throw;` instead of `throw GenExp` - as the latter loses the call stack. Although if you're really doing nothing more than a rethrow then just omit the whole catch block.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (Exception unknownException)
{
   throw new Exception("Unknown error.", unknownException);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
catch 
{}
```

Is also valid code and catches all exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Important Notice!

It is a extremely BAD programming style - to use of similar constructions:

```
try
{
  // smth
}
catch(IOException e)
{
   throw e;
}
```

It means, that the exception stack will begin with this point (of stack), and you can lose any stack frames, which are lower than this point.

Correct:

```
 try
    {
      //smth
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      throw;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1- i think you was supposed to do this by yourself.

2- catch (XmlException) //valid
    {
       return false; 
    }
    catch (XmlSchemaException)   //valid 
    {
       return false; 
    }
    catch (Exception GenExp)
    {
       throw GenExp;
    }
    //valid but doesn't make sense because the Exception will happen and there is no try catch block to handel it